# Visual Studio 2013 WP Emulator not working after adding more RAM

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-emulator

After a few days I installed VS 2013 on my laptop which had 3GB RAM and got notified by visual studio that I need at least 4 GB for hardware  virtualization. Now I have 6GB RAM and Hyper-V restarted and VS still doesn't recognize my new RAM and doesn't give me an option to run the WP emulator.

Did any of you had a problem/soulution for this?

Comment: Are you being indicated of any errors?

Comment: No, it just doesn't give me the option in the drop down menu... only "Device" (as a hardware device)

Comment: You sure, you ticked the `Windows Phone SDK` when you were installing?

Comment: Yes, I installed it. I have downloaded now the Emulator updates and again the same error... http://screencast.com/t/xThGiFLEu6

Comment: Did you try to `Repair` it?

Comment: Just a quick question: 32bit or 64bit OS?  You going to need a 64 bit OS if you want more than 4GB showing esp. if you have a video card taking up the available space as well.

Comment: Are the WP emulators showing up in hyper-v manager?  You have Win8.1 *Professional*, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, its my processor. After buying new RAM I thought I solved the issue but my processor is Intel B940 and this series does not support virtualization :(

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Hyper-V is enabled. If not, enabling Hyper-V will slove the issue.